# Spring: Mapping two POST fields to three RESULT fields

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

In the post "Hello World" phase of my Spring journey. Creating an app that `POSTS` two fields which `RESULT` in three fields.

My controller has three fields.  Two are populated on POST, and all three should populate the RESULT fields.

The Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class GreetController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
public class Greeting {

    //fields correspond to greeting.html
    private long id;
    private String content;
    private String numbah;

    public String getNumbah() { return numbah; }
    public void setNumbah() {
        this.numbah = SomeFunctions.functionOne(this.getContent());
    }

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getContent() { return content; }
    public void setContent(String content) { this.content }

}
```

The View:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
this is greeting.html
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<!--th.fields correspond to fields in th.object (ie greeting.java)-->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>

<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
<p th:text="'numbah: ' + ${greeting.numbah}" />

<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:

The `${greeting.numbah}` field, as configured above, is resulting in null.  I had a log statement in that function that never returned anything, indicating that the function in the model is never firing.  However, when the view was configured like this...

```
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<!--th.fields correspond to fields in th.object (ie greeting.java)-->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p>Some Number: <input type="text" th:field="*{numbah}"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>

<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
<p th:text="'numbah: ' + ${greeting.numbah}" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
```

...the field was populating, so the function itself....functions.

Long short, what I'm attempting to do here is take `id` and `content`, do `someFunction(content)=numbah` and return `id`, `content`, and `numbah`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It always gets down to something simple, doesn't it?

There was a typo in the `setNumbah` constructor in the model.

This is why I hardly ever post on sites like this: because you almost always figure out what you did wrong if you just sleep on it and have another look.

Thanks for checking this out and apologies that it's not a "high quality" problem/answer.  Will delete if that's the protocol for a self-answered question.

Comment: No need to delete. Self-answering is ok.